# iOS 11 MPNowPlayingInfoCenter not showing details

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I play some audio files with `AVPlayer` and now I want to display track info in Control Center or on the Lock screen.

I set it up like this:

```
    NSDictionary *info = @{
                        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: @"Test",
                        MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: @"Test",
                        MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:  @"Test",
                        MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate :@1.0f };

        [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter]setNowPlayingInfo:info];
```

and also added

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

but the result is the same as described here [How to set audio details with an image on control center in Objective-C for iOS11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285207/how-to-set-audio-details-with-an-image-on-control-center-in-objective-c-for-ios1) everything is just greyed out and no info is showing.

Comment: To become the Now Playing app you need to set up a non mixable audio session category, like this: `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&nil];`.

Comment: Ok I did that now, but unfortunately that didn't change anything. It's still the same.

Comment: You also have to be playing audio.

Comment: Well yeah of course I do that.

Comment: Have you called setActive on the session?

Comment: Yes I did that aswell.

Comment: Can you make a small project that reproduces the problem and link to it here?